# How to pass a table type parameter to SQLExecute?

Tags: databaselink, databases

In MS SQL Server 2016 I have a table type parameter:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.Ids AS TABLE (Id INTEGER NOT NULL);
```

and a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TableParam  @SelectedIds dbo.Ids READONLY AS
BEGIN SELECT * FROM @SelectedIds; END
```

In *Mathematica* I have a selection of ids that I want to pass into the SQL procedure.  However, I have not been able to figure out the syntax. The following does not work.

```
SQLExecute[conn, "dbo.TableParam `1`", {{{5}, {6}, {7}}}]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't you have one pair of braces too much?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries `SQLExecute` is expecting a list of arguments with the list of ids being the first item in the list. The real SQL procedure takes a few arguments with one of them being the table type.